# How to make sure mySQL database takes values only from my game?

Tags: mysql, database, security, encryption, hash

I have coded a simple snake like game in Java. I want to store the high scores of users in a database and so I have created a mySQL database. The problem I'm facing is having the program connect to the mySQL database without leaking the login information which will allow users to mess with the database. I have looked into it and everyone has suggested a web service in the middle between the game and the SQL database. However the problem is still there and anyone can feed data which can again mess up the database.

One option I've thought of is having the jar file uploaded along with the data to the web service. The web service then gets the hash value (was looking into SAH 512) and compares it to the hash value that it's suppose to get and if matches then it proceeds. But then someone can just reverse engineer my game and change the code a bit and send the original game file but send a different NAME+SCORE to the database. Also having people keep uploading files to the web service would be a huge pain on my network because it could handle only so much considering I'm using a home network.

I could encrypt some file with the password on but since the program is able to decrypt it then surely the user will be able to decrypt it and get the information as well.

Basically anyway I provide the program with a key to my database someone will be able to reverse engineer it and edit it so that they are able to access my database. That's my thought behind it. Anyway I provide the program a way to access the database someone will also be able to use that way to mess with the database if they wanted to.

There must be a way for me to be able to store information from my game onto a mySQL database and making sure that nobody is able to change stuff around it but only the program that I've made is able to. Somehow to hide the details behind a service or something. How the hell do other people do it? Can I have some guidance? Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, applications shouldn't make direct connections to a database, rather they make calls to a server that has db access.

Comment: Yes but how will the server know if the program is who it's suppose to be? Someone can reverse engineer my game and change the code a little and then start communicating with the  server as if they are the game. They can then start messing with the database. You need a way for the server to be able to identify the game and make sure the requests are trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can not get a guarantee for that. The application can always be decompiled and its behavior changed.

If you accept this limit, you can guarantee a certain level of security by using a middle layer (web service). Here, you can guarantee a secure transport layer (SSL) and trustworthy login through a user certificate placed in the app. You can also add a digital signature to the sent data.

This will give you a fairly reliable system whose drilling will need to decompile the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is an age old problem, and there is no easy solution to it. For some scenarios, it can be solved, but for others it cannot.

The basic rule is, anything you do in the client is pretty much useless in terms of security. As you said, anybody can decompile and analyse your client-side code, obtain any secrets and so on. The user has full control of the client, and therefore, you cannot trust data (scores) sent by the client.

So you need a server-side solution, and that's where it starts to get interesting. What you can actually do is you can send the whole flow of the game (all the events) to the server to be able to fully (or at least in part) reconstruct what happened - server side. The score doesn't even need to be sent then, you can calculate it from how the game went in the client.

For single player skill games, this doesn't help, the user can still construct the whole flow like he was playing really well. But on the one hand, that's much harder than just to fake a score, and on the other hand, there may be games, where coming up with a solution is the point. Especially for games that are NP-hard, finding the solution is indeed the trick, verifying it is easy.

Also for multiplayer games, this would help, because if all players submit the flow, those flows received must match, otherwise there is a cheater (or all the players are cheaters, or the same cheater is playing as all the players, but you should be able to prevent that then by other means).

If you have the whole flow of the game, you can also implement other anti-cheating techniques, like for example if it's a skill game, you can try to find actions that appear super-human. It will never be perfect, and the difficulty then is not to mark legitimate players as cheaters.

Answer (score 0):

it depends a little...

one example that will at least make it a little harder for someone who wants to mess with your game could be like this:

if your game is procedurally generating content, store and transmit the initial seed ... then do not just transmit the score and a name...

store and transmit all player decisions that lead to a specific score

let your server replay the game based on the provided seed and decisions, and take the score that was calculated on the server

so... to forge a score you need to solve the game (or an automated approach for this)

this approach does make it harder to fake a score, but it does not bind a name and a score together (you could submit the same score with a different name later ...)

to add that you can change things a little further:

online scores require online games ...

when a game is started, ask for the players name ...

post that name to the server, to aquire a HMAC (Hashed Message Authentication Code) secured token, containing an ID (think of an GUID) and the server generated starting seed

the server stores name and ID, and gives out a limited number of tokens per timespan and IP

the token is valid for a timespan x, after that you can delete it if it was not "used" within that timespan

when the player finished the game, you can provide this token, together with the players decisions to the server

the server knows who the player is, and can recreated the final gamestate and find the score

systems like this do not prevent all forms of cheating, but they are usually not that hard to implement and demand at least a little more effort from an attacker, thus filtering out the script kiddies